# create simple lingvo .dsl dict using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have some text files and every file contains a definition for a word and looks like this:

```
word1
<TAB> some text 
<TAB> some text
title 1
<TAB> some text
<TAB> some text
title 2
<TAB> some text
.
.
```

I want to create a simple *lingvo .DSL* dictionary so the desired output should be like this :

```
word1
[m2][trn]
<TAB> some text 
<TAB> some text
[b]title 1[/b]
<TAB> some text
<TAB> some text
[b]title 2[/b]
<TAB> some text
<TAB> some text
.
.
[/m2][/trn]
```

so what I need to do is  :

- add `[m2][trn]` after the first word .
- if a line begins with a letter or a number (not a tab) so it's a title and should be  `[b]title[/b]`
- Add `[/m2][/trn]` to the end of the file .

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: yes ,i have read some examples and tutorials about sed but i am not a sed guru ,i know how to search for a lines begin with a letter or a number but i don't know how to exclude the first word .

Comment: Your sample output shows `[B]` and `[/B]`; your text specification says `[b]` and `[/b]`.  They're different, so one of the two is incorrect.  Is either correct?  If the language is case-insensitive, then you should say so, and presumably `[M2][TRN]` etc would also be OK.

Comment: sorry  i edited that ,it's lowercase ,this is a .dsl dictionary format by lingvo and this format is supported by my favourite dictionary program called goldendict .
[this is a sample](https://github.com/Tvangeste/SampleDSL/blob/master/sample.dsl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**analysis**

> 1. add [m2][trn] after the first word.
>
>    ```
>    use a head splitter to handle the first line differently from the rest. 
>    and just printf this start tag.
>    ```
> 2. if a line begins with a letter or a number (not a tab) so it's a title and should be  [b]title[/b]
>
>    ```
>    sed to search for lines starting with word characters \w
>    ```
> 3. Add [/m2][/trn] to the end of the file .
>
>    ```
>    printf to add end tag
>    ```

**example script**

```
head -n 1 input.txt 1>output.txt;
printf "[m2][trn]\n" 1>>output.txt;
tail -n +2 input.txt | 
  sed 's/^\(\w\+.\+\)/[b]\1[\/b]/g' 1>>output.txt;
printf "[/m2][/trn]\n" 1>>output.txt;
```

**output**

```
word1
[m2][trn]
    some text 
    some text
[b]title 1[/b]
    some text
    some text
[b]title 2[/b]
    some text
[/m2][/trn]
```

Comment: this is my first post so i can't vote ,thanks for ur help .

Comment: @wissam thats ok dude

Comment: Ouch.  Yes, I can see it works, and how it works, but it involves many commands.  You could use `sed -e 1d -e 's/…/…/' input.txt` in place of the `tail | sed` combo.  You could usefully use: `{ cmd1; cmd2; …; } > output.txt` to avoid repeated I/O redirection.  But more significantly, you can do the whole lot with a single `sed` script, which is bound to be at least a bit quicker.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes could definitely combine some ( even all of these commands ), as Jahid has done. for non-sed experts like me, i would have to RTM to understand what the 1, 1!, and ampersands actually do. my answer is not the most technically efficient, but for me more intuitive and maintainable ways to meet the specified functionality. 6 months from now ill still be able to read this long after ive forgotten my reading on what the ampersand does in sed

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

```
sed '1! { /^[[:alnum:]]/ s/.*/[b]&[\/b]/; }; 1 s/$/\n[m2][trn]/; $ s/$/\n[\/trn][\/m2]/' filename
```

That is:

```
1! { /^[[:alnum:]]/ s/.*/[b]&[\/b]/; } # If the current line is not the first and
                                       # starts with a letter or number, encase
                                       # it in [b][/b]
1 s/$/\n[m2][trn]/                     # If the current line is the first, put
                                       # [m2][trn] behind it
$ s/$/\n[\/trn][\/m2]/                 # If the current line is the last, put
                                       # [/trn][/m2] behind it.
```

Comment: Are the semi colons inside at the end of the braces needed ?

Comment: Thnx Wintermute ,but for some reason it add [b] at the beginning of every line and [/b] to the end of every line .

Comment: Not for GNU sed, but BSD sed requires them.

Comment: @wissam Do the lines you marked as beginning with a tab really begin with tabs, or could spaces have snuck in there? If so, replace `/^\t/!` with `/^[[:alnum:]]/`.

Comment: wintermute : no spaces ,all tabs ,I don't know why it add [b] and [\b] to every line except the first and the last .

Comment: Hmm...are you using Mac OS X, per chance? (Also, does it work with `/^[[:alnum:]]/` instead of `/\^t/!` (mind the `!`)?)

Comment: No i am using manjaro linux,i had to go out,i am on android now ,i'll try that when i come back . Thnx man

Comment: @Wintermute Sorry for the late replay , it works perfectly with  `{ /^[[:alnum:]]/ }`

Comment: @wissam Hm. Odd that it shouldn't work with `/^\t/!` if all the other lines begin with a tab (works for me, anyway). My suspicion is that there's another character before the tab, but of course I have no way of checking that. I guess I'll just patch the answer, then.

Comment: @Wintermute thnx it worked with `/^\t/!` ,i tried it with some other files ,i guess there is some space  in that file i have tried before ,i can't check that again because i replaced all leading spaces with tab in all files using sed to be sure no errors will occur.
Thanks for your help again .

Comment: Well, ultimately what matters is that you use a pattern that reliably separates the lines that should be `[b][/b]`-ed from those that shouldn't. From the description I figured that "doesn't begin with a tab" would be the best option, but if there's a danger that spaces sneak in, then it's better to approach from the other direction. I'd probably consider something like `/^[^[:space:]]/` (or `/^\S/`, if you can depend on GNU sed), meaning lines that begin with a character that's not a space, but ultimately you know the constraints of the data set better than I.

Comment: By the way, is there a reason you close the `m2` and `trn` tags crosswise in the question?

Comment: yes , `trn` and `\trn` means translation zone , `mN`  and `\mN` define the left paragraph margin where  N is the number of spaces .The dictionary format is used by lingvo and explained [here](https://github.com/Tvangeste/SampleDSL/blob/master/sample.dsl) and [here](http://goldendict.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=751&hilit=[%2Fm2][%2Ftrn])

Answer (score 1):

This sed command should do it:

```
sed -e '1s/$/\n[m2][trn]/'          \
-e '1!s/^[a-Z0-9].*/[B]&[\/B]/'     \
-e '$s/$/\n[\/m2][\/trn]/'          \
 file
```